# loop through json array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I have this json a array of object 
and I want to loop through and display all parents with its child

```
[
    {
        "ProfessionName": "Technique ",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 1,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    },
    {
        "ProfessionName": "Production ",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "1",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 2,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    },
    {
        "ProfessionName": "Maintenance ",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "1",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 3,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    },
    {
        "ProfessionName": "Maintenance Unit Manager",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "3",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 4,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    },
    {
        "ProfessionName": "Maintenance operator",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "3",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 5,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    },
    {
        "ProfessionName": "Liquid maintenance operator",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "3",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 6,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    },
    {
        "ProfessionName": "Production Unit Manager",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "2",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 7,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    },
    {
        "ProfessionName": "project manager",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "2",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 8,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    },
    {
        "ProfessionName": "Machine operator",
        "ParentProfessionNum": "2",
        "ParentProfession": null,
        "Id": 9,
        "RowVersion": null,
        "RowRevision": null
    }
]
```

I did follows 
first I split parents and child in separate arrays
if parent then ParentProfessionNum must be null
and if child this should have an ID of another array

```
$parents = array();
$childs = array();
foreach ($data as $job) {
     if (!$job['ParentProfessionNum']) {
       array_push($parents, $job);
     } else {
       array_push($childs, $job);
       }
     };
```

then I did a loop using foreach

```
foreach ($parents as $p) {
   echo $p['ProfessionName'];
   $parent_id = $p['Id'];
   foreach ($childs as $c) {
       if ((int) $c['ParentProfessionNum'] == $parent_id) {
          echo $c['ProfessionName'];
       }
   }
}
```

but this shows only first parent's child.

**Update**
this is the output 
Technique (parent)
Production (child)
Maintenance (child)

but also these child are parent for another child
I want to display them all as tree view or any other way

Comment: you are missing the [ at the beginning?

Comment: question updated

Comment: ah ok, can i use other code or i should stay on your?

Answer (score 2):

You have never set `$parent_id`... use instead `$p['id']` or set `$parent_id = $p['id']`

Also the `(int)` cast is useless until you use `==` because PHP will check for equality of value and not type, so `1=="1"` is true, instead `1==="1"` is false, and so the cast is needed

So the code should be

```php
foreach ($data as $p) {
    echo "PARENT : ".$p->ProfessionName."\n";
    $parent_id = $p->Id;
    echo "CHILDREN : \n";
    foreach ($data as $c) {
        if ($c->ParentProfessionNum == $parent_id) {
            echo $c->ProfessionName."\n";
        }
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: yes, it works
but the output shows only the first parent-child

Comment: there is only one parent... only one element has "" as ParentProfessionNum, so there is only one parent, and the script show all the children of this parent "Technique Production Maintenance"

Comment: check "Maintenance operator" it's a child of Maintenance, so Maintenance is a child and also a parent

Comment: yes but you are adding to $parents only the ones that haven't a ParentProfessionNum value.

Comment: your definition of parent is someone without child?

Comment: it's almost like tree view
,every element may have child or maybe not, and start with one or more root element

Comment: check if there this solution does what you want (edited the answere)

Answer (score 1):

inside child for loop

replace if statement's condition from

```
if ((int) $c['ParentProfessionNum'] == $parent_id) {
```

with

```
if ((int) $c['ParentProfessionNum'] == $p['id']) {
```

after analyzing your array, if objects with `ProfessionName` "Production" and "Maintenance " are also parents
than you should make `"ParentProfessionNum"` empty or null

```
"ParentProfessionNum" = ""
```

instead of

```
"ParentProfessionNum" = "1"
```

**UPDATE** (based on the question update)
with some object being both child and parent at a time,

you need more attributes (let's say `is_parent` and `is_child`) and then separate using child and parent using those attributes so some of the objects wil be on both arrays parent and child

```
foreach ($data as $job) {
  if ($job['is_parent']) {
    array_push($parents, $job);
  } 
  if ($job['is_child']) {
    array_push($childs, $job);
  }
};
```

Comment: I did, but the problem is I need to loop through and show all child for every parent

Comment: so what is the output if you put the condition like `(int) $c['ParentProfessionNum'] == $p['id']`

Comment: the output shows first parent and his child
Technique(parent) Production(child) Maintenance(child)
but Production and Maintenance are parent too and have child
I need to keep the loop and display all child

Comment: but as per the condition you put while separating child and parent `(!$job['ParentProfessionNum'])` will push only one item into parent because it only has empty `ParentProfessionNum`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a logic problem.

The first step should be to get all the parents.
Then loop through the array of parents and print all the children for that parent 
So,

```
// Get the unique values of parent Ids
$parentsIndex = array_unique(array_column($data, 'ParentProfessionNum'));
sort($parentsIndex);

//Loop through the parents
foreach ($parentsIndex as $key=>$p) {
  // Skip Technique in parent
  if("" != $p) {
    // get the index for the original parent element in $data
    $key = $p-1;

    //always check if index exists 
    if (isset($data[$key]['ProfessionName'])) {
      // Print Parent
      echo $data[$key]['ProfessionName']."\n";
    }

    // Print children
    foreach ($data as $c) {
      //always check if index exists 
      if (isset($c['ParentProfessionNum'])) {
        if ($c['ParentProfessionNum'] == $p  ) {
          echo "   " . $c['ProfessionName']."\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```